# Как добавить на фон HTML документа картинку?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить на фон HTML-документа картинку?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, в любом случае будет необходимо добавить стили.
Если не создавать отдельный .css файл, то можно в  добавить стили инлайново:

```
<body style="background-image: url('http://... .jpg'); background-size: cover">
   Some HTML
</body>
```